# FillRect Psychtoolbox constantly causing error

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

My code:

```
Screen('OpenWindow', 0, [0 0 0], [0 0 600 600])
Screen('FillRect', win, [0 255 0 ], [0 0 50 50]);
Screen('Flip', win);
```

I understand that the documented line is:

```
Screen('FillRect', windowPtr [,color] [,rect] )
```

With `windowPtr` as just a placeholder which needs to be replaced with a variable name to identify this particular shape. However when I'm using win to identify it, I am constantly getting the error:

> Undefined function or variable 'win'.
>   Error in Practice_Script_1 (line 17)
>   Screen('FillRect', win, [0 255 0 ], [0 0 50 50]);

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and it's probably just some noob mistake that is really frustrating me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the Psychtoolbox, but this error message typically means that the (in this case) `win` variable is not defined.  Have you initialized this variable prior to calling the above lines of code?

The following link [creating experiments using MATLAB and Psychtoolbox](http://www.academia.edu/2614964/Creating_experiments_using_Matlab_and_Psychtoolbox) has some sample code and they define the `win` variable as

```
win = Screen('OpenWindow',0, [900 900 1000], [10,10, 1100,1100]);
```

You will need to do something similar.  Another link [MATLAB cookbook](http://wiki.stdout.org/matlabcookbook/Presenting%20visual%20stimuli/Initializing%20the%20display%20and%20showing%20basic%20shapes/) does the following

```
% Initialize the screen with a black background
% rect is the coordinates of the screen
[win rect] = Screen('OpenWindow', 0, [0 0 0]);

ovalColor = [0 255 0];         % RGB color for the oval
rectColor = [255 0 0];         % RGB color for the rectangle
ovalRect  = [100 100 300 200]; % Coordinates [x1 y1 x2 y2]
rectRect  = [100 250 300 350]; % Coordinates [x1 y1 x2 y2]

Screen('FillOval', win, ovalColor, ovalRect);
Screen('FillRect', win, rectColor, rectRect);
Screen('Flip', win);
```

Try either option  and see what happens.

Comment: The first option worked after a bit of fiddling.I had to remove the first line of code and replace it with the first option. Thank You!